# React native background task

Tags: react-native

Is there a library on RN that can do this? Like in android, there are some apps when you upload files, it sends a push notification on your phone monitoring the progress, even when you kill the app?

Comment: what do you want perform in the background task?

Answer (score 1):

This library supports this: [react-native-background-job](https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job) (Disclaimer: I'm the author).

When this is written (Dec. 2016) it is Android only since it requires ReactNative's HeadlessJS which is not available for iOS yet.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late. But Will be helpful for folks in future.

You can go with the below link. the library is exclusively for Uploading as u mentioned.

[Background task](https://github.com/Vydia/react-native-background-upload)